# Two setting backgrounds and sleeping a thread

Tags: java, actionlistener

I want to change the color of JTextField to red after typing something in it, and then after a second return to a default white background. I tried this outside the listener, and it worked, but when it comes to being a part of a listener, it doesn't (it just skips setting the red color). This is weird for me..

```
public class Test {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField field;

    public Test() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        field = new JTextField("A");
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyBListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Test(); }

    private class KeyBListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            try {
                field.setBackground(Color.RED);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            } catch (InterruptedException es) { es.printStackTrace(); }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  For updates like this they have to happen outside the EDT otherwise, you block the repainting of the display.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a separate `Thread` that listens to color change on the `JTextField` then changes it back. In this case at least you will not block the main Thread, although I'm not sure it's the most efficient way.

```
public Main() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    field = new JTextField("A");
    field.addKeyListener(new KeyBListener());
    frame.getContentPane().add(field);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    new Thread(() -> {
        while(true) {
            if(field.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, wonder if there's another method. I thought about creating the thread inside the ``listener``, but starting one thread on every key press is again kind of bad ..

Answer (score 0):

Your previous solution was working because it was executed from the AWT itself.

The `keyTyped()` method is executed on the Event dispatch thead (EDT), so you have to move the painting actions back to the AWT.

Have a look on `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (non-blocking) or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` (blocking), see
[Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      field.setBackground(Color.RED);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    } catch (InterruptedException es) { 
      es.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a different thread in which you do the color manipulation. That ensures that the color manipulation is not happening inside EDT.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField field;
    AtomicBoolean isColorChangeOn = new AtomicBoolean();
    public Test() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        field = new JTextField("A");
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyBListener());
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        isColorChangeOn.set(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private class KeyBListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if(!isColorChangeOn.get()) {
                    isColorChangeOn.set(true);
                    Runnable setcolor = ()->{
                        try {
                            System.out.println("color changing");
                            field.setBackground(Color.RED);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                            isColorChangeOn.set(false);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    };
                    new Thread(setcolor).start();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```